# Counting nodes with a specific value in a binary tree

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

I am trying to come up with a way to traverse a binary tree recursively versus iteratively and count how many times a find a specific value. One issue I'm running into is root in the first method.

Node inner class:

```
private class Node {

    int data;
    Node root;
    Node left;
    Node right;
}
```

Recursive & helper method:

```
public int valCount(int val) {
    if (root != null) {
        return valCount(val, root);
    }
    return 0;
}

public int valCount(int val, Node root) {
    int cnt = 0;
    if (root.left != null) {
        if (root.left.data == val) {
            cnt++;
        }
        valCount(val, root.left);
    }


    if (root.right != null) {
        if (root.right.data == val) {
            cnt++;
        }
        valCount(val, root.right);
    }
    return cnt;
}
```

I haven't been able to test because of the root issue so I'm not entirely sure my output will be correct. So, the question begs to be asked... am I even on the right track?? Does my approach even make sense? Any help would be awesome. Cheers!

Comment: Pass `cnt` also in the recursive call and define `cnt` in the `class` scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time `valCount` is called, a **separate** copy of the local variable `cnt` is created.  Thus when you call `valCount` for the root, this creates a variable `cnt`; when `valCount` then calls itself for the left or right subtree, the new `valCount` has its **own** `cnt`, so when they increment `cnt`, they do *not* increment the `cnt` that the first `valCount` owns.  This means that all the work done by `valCount` for the left and right subtrees is thrown away.

A simple way to fix this would be to notice that when you call `valCount` for the left or right subtree, the recursive call will return a value.  You should use that value, instead of discarding the result:

```
int leftCount = valCount(val, root.left);
```

and then do something with `leftCount` (I'll let you think about how to use it).

**EDIT:** One more thing: `valCount` should look at `root.data`, but it shouldn't look at `root.left.data` or `root.right.data`.  Let the recursive calls do the work of looking at the data in the subtrees.  That's how binary tree recursion often works.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need "root" in your Node class. The "root" is the "this" object/pointer, right? Pass another parameter "int[] cnt" to valCount. Instantiate cnt as int[1]. Then in valCount do cnt[0]++. In the calling function after your recursion ends, print out cnt[0]. And remove the cnt local variable.

Answer (score -1):

each time you call the method recursively a new object of cnt will be created that takes the value 0. Which means each time you increment it the value is lost.
A good way to fix this is by placing cnt in the parameter of the method, and therefore each time you call it you pass the new value of cnt.

Comment: This is just a low-quality rephrasing of the accepted answer.